# How do I make a generic container in Go?

Tags: go

Suppose I need to implement pagination in Go. I need to pass around a struct with elements and some paging information. So I thought of this:

```
type PagedStruct struct {
    elements *[]interface{}
    page     int16
    total    int16
}
```

which contains a pointer to an array that can be of any type. Because I've more than one place in my code where I need to paginate, this seems a sensible solution to reuse the code.

But then I try to use this like:

```
users := []User{
        User{1, "", "", "", ""},
    }
return &PagedStruct{&users, 1, 1}
```

and it does not work, saying IncompatibleAssign . Could not find a good solution for this on google.

Comment: [The Next Steps for Generics](https://blog.golang.org/generics-next-step)

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface. As `interface{}` doesn't mean "any type", `[]interface{}` doesn't mean "a slice of any type".

Comment: Just some tips: 1. Don't use pointer to slice. 2. Read [this](https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface) from the Go FAQ.  3. The problem with generic / polymorphic code like this in Go is that it's impossible to give sensible guidance about the design until you demonstrate how the data type is actually used.

Comment: so what could be a good solution? (Instead of downvoting my question...)

Comment: can anyone give a reason why this question has been downvoted and asked to close? what is wrong apart from me being new to Go?

Comment: Most likely because this has been covered extensively, here and elsewhere, and the default downvote reason is for lack of research. Without any example data it's also overly broad, as there are lots of possible patterns to deal with types at runtime. For some examples of containers to store any type, did you look at the 3 containers types in the standard library? In most cases you will find that you don't actually need generic code, and can use the known types already.

Comment: maybe you dont need that data here. Maybe if you had an int to store len of elements that would work too. Maybe that int could be an int64 so any count operations made from this or that db would work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if it is the case that you are done with the data and you just want to pass the `PagedStruct` to the client, and assuming you're doing so through something that works on data with type `interface{}` using [`reflection`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/), e.g. [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) or [`html/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/), then most likely all you need is change the field's type from `*[]interface{}` to `interface{}`.

```golang
type PagedStruct struct {
    Data  interface{} `json:"data"`
    Page  int16       `json:"page"`
    Total int16       `json:"total"`
}
```

```golang
func ListUsers(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    users := []*User{
        // get users from db
    }

    page := PagedStruct{Data: users, Page: 1, Total: 1}
    if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(page); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}

// or


func ListUsers(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    users := []*User{
        // get users from db
    }

    page := PagedStruct{Data: users, Page: 1, Total: 1}
    if err := listUsersTemplate.Execute(w, page); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine:

```
package main
import "fmt"

type (
   user []interface{}
   page struct {
      elements []user
   }
)

func main() {
   users := []user{
      {1, "south"}, {2, "north"},
   }
   p := page{users}
   fmt.Printf("%+v\n", p) // {elements:[[1 south] [2 north]]}
}
```